# Visual Studio 2010 and Rational tools for source control

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, version-control

We have licenses for Visual Studio 2010 and our client only has rational tools licenses.

What Rational software is installed on a server to store .Net source code? We have a Windows 2008 R2 server.

What Rational software is installed on the client to allow Visual Studio 2010 to pull/store code, check in and check out code?

We only need source control...do not care about the other suites in Rational.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a non-distributed form of source control, like SVN, Rational ClearCase has a way to integrate with VisualStudio (see http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21421687).  Versions 7.1.1 and 8.x should work on Windows Server 2008 R2.

Unfortunately, their distributed source control system, Rational Jazz, comes with much more than an SCM.  Albeit, Rational Team Concert, the client to Jazz, does have Visual Studio integration (https://jazz.net/products/rational-team-concert/features/vsclient).  If you need a distributed source control from IBM you could use that and ignore the extra features?  They used to have just Jazz SCM, but I haven't been able to find a standalone copy of that.